# POST HTTP Request from iOS to RESTful WCF Service .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, ios, objective-c, wcf

I am trying to create a POST request out to a WCF web service written in C# running on IIS7 .NET Framework 4.0.

The web service works for GET requests however I cannot seem to get POST methods working. Some background is that I was using PHP for the server side before having to switch to .NET.

Code for my request in iOS:

```
NSArray *jsonKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zip", nil];
NSArray *jsonValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: zipcode, nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:jsonValues forKeys:jsonKeys];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/weather", ConnectionString3]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

C# Code for WCF Web service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/weather")]
List<Weather> GetWeatherMethod(string zip);
```

I logged the response on the iOS side which shows an XML response from the server that an error occurred and to check the server side log, which I can't seem to find anything wrong with. Any help would be appreciated.

Only log from the server I can find reads:

```
(Date and Time) (Server IP) POST /PeopleService/PeopleService.svc/weather - 80 - (local app ip) AppName/1.0+CFNetwork/609+Darwin/11.4.2 400 0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you post more debugging output from server? Like the webmethod ever gets executed? What error is faced?

Comment: Where can I find detailed logs on the server? The only thing I seem to have is a log file showing each request made to the server and from what ip. And from what I can tell, it's not updating the log

Comment: I don't like to see "400" at the log, please add the response headers and content if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by response headers and content? If you mean what the last three fields represent (400 0 0 0), they are (sc-status, sc-substatus, sc-win32-status and time taken). If you mean what is the json string i'm sending, that is {"zip":"30309"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you declared the body style of the operation as `Bare`, but you're sending the data you want the parameter to receive *wrapped* in the parameter name.

If you declare the operation as

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
           UriTemplate = "/weather")]
List<Weather> GetWeatherMethod(string zip);
```

You can send the request body as `{"zip":"30309"}` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the problem by creating a class such that the JSON would map to it.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/weather")]
List<Weather> GetWeatherMethod(ZipCodeJSON zipJson);

[DataContract]
public class ZipCodeJSON
{
    [DataMember]
    public string zip { get; set; }
}
```